# Laravel 5 Json with relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have this code, is a table with relatioship it self:

Category Model

```
class Cateogry extends Model {
    public function subCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\SubCategory');
    }
}
```

SubCategory Model

```
<?php
class SubCategory extends Model {
    public function Category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category');
    }
}
```

In your controller

SomeController

```
<?php 

class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        return Category::with('subCategory')->get()
    }
}
```

when i do the return Category::with('subCategory')->get();
he prints:

```
{
            "id": 43,
            "name": "Quartos",
            "subcategories_id": null,
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 43,
                    "name": "Quartos",
                    "subcategories_id": null
                }
            ]
        }
    {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Jovenil",
        "subcategories_id": 2,
        "sub_category": [
            {
                "id": 55,
                "name": "Jovenil",
                "subcategories_id": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

instead:

```
{
            "id": 43,
            "name": "Quartos",
            "subcategories_id": null,
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "name": "Casal",
                    "subcategories_id": 1
                }
                {
                    "id": 51,
                    "name": "Jovenil",
                    "subcategories_id": 2
                }(...)
            ]
        }
```

why the query does that?

Comment: I don't understand. Please fix your spelling errors and explain more thoroughly what is going on

Answer (score 0):

just try this and test your code, and also share your results

`return Category::with('subCategory')->where('id',43)->get();`

Comment: The result is:
[
    {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "Quartos",
        "subcategories_id": null,
        "sub_category": [
            {
                "id": 43,
                "name": "Quartos",
                "subcategories_id": null
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: does results ok ? or still missing. please verify your DB records, means check that how many records exists against `Category ID 43`

Comment: I sould appear only once. i my db the id 43 is category "quartos". in the json appears with category and subcategory. The result be : "quartos":{'casal','jevenil'}

Comment: tell me you `primary` and `foreign` key names?

Answer (score 0):

I change this:

```
Category Model

class Cateogry extends Model {
    public function subCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\SubCategory');
    }
} 

SubCategory Model

<?php
class SubCategory extends Model {
    public function Category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category');
    }
}
```

to this:

```
    class Subcategory extends Model {

        protected $table="categories";
        public $timestamps = false;

        public function Category() {
            return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category','id');
        }

    }

class Category extends Model {

    protected $table="categories";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function subCategory() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Subcategory','subcategories_id');
    }

}
```

And works fine, thanks Qazi for our help